# Convert ObjectiveC expression in SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm implementing a simple app that will download data from Google Maps and I will display this data on a Map. I implemented all the code to get this information from Google, now I'm trying to implement the method to decode the polyline. I've the following method written in ObjectiveC:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine:(NSString *)encodedStr {
    NSMutableString *encoded = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:[encodedStr length]];
    [encoded appendString:encodedStr];
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                                options:NSLiteralSearch
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5];
        NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5];

        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]];
        [array addObject:location];
    }

    return array;
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement this method in SWIFT, but I'm having issue in the following instruction:
`NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));`, I tried to write it in the following way:

`var dlng: NSInteger = (result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1)`

but Xcode says me: `Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'`and I don't know how to fix this issue, there's someone that can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
(result & 1)
```

In objective C an integer can be used as a boolean expression, where 0 corresponds to false and any value different than zero is true. In this specific case, it's true if the rightmost bit is 1, false otherwise.

In swift a logical expression must be of boolean type, so what you need to do is just transform it as follows:

```
(result & 1) > 0
```

**Update**: since in this case you're dealing with a `NSInteger`, which can have positive and negative values, maybe it's better to think in that terms, and use "different than zero" instead of "greater than zero":

```
(result & 1) != 0
```